# Notation in mixed effects models

Tags: regression, mixed-model, python, pymc, bambi

I have started reading about [Bambi](https://github.com/bambinos/bambi) and I don't quite understand its notation.

For example what does the following `random=['condition|subject', '1|stimulus']` mean below?

```
from bambi import Model
# Assume we already have our data loaded
model = Model(data)
results = model.fit('rt ~ condition', random=['condition|subject', '1|stimulus'], samples=5000)
results.plot(burn_in=1000)
results.summary(1000)
```

Comment: You introduces the new tag `bambi` Can you explain it, maybe write a tag wiki?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like very similar notation to that used in other mixed effects packages.

There are 2 random intercepts, for `stimulus` and `subject` because these appear after the `|` in the formula, and there are random slopes for `condition` for each level of `subject` (because `condition` appears on the left of the `|` in the formula).

Comment: Thanks, so is the assumption that data has the following factors (columns): `rt`, `condition`, `stimulus` and `subject`? Also, what exactly would the formula be for this particular model?

Comment: When you said: "there are random slopes for `condition` for each level of `subject`"  you meant to say: "there are random slopes for `subject` for each level of `condition`", correct?

Comment: @Josh no I meant it the way I wrote it. Each level of `subject` (the random intercept) will have its own value for `condition` - those values will tropically be normally distributed around a mean of zero, and if `condition` is also a fixed effect then each `subject`'s `condition`will be the sum of the fixed and random part. This may or may not be what was intended but that would be the usual interpretation.

Comment: Thanks Robert. Hmm, this isn't consistent with what the developer of `bambi` (the library in in my post) [just said](https://github.com/bambinos/bambi/issues/79). I quote: "By convention, the `|` is a grouping operator. In the above example, `condition|subject` means that a separate set of `subject` slopes is being estimated for each level of the `condition` factor."